# How to fetch Mac OS network configuration

Tags: objective-c, macos

### Background

I'm developing application which monitors machines in corporate network.
Each machines will run my application and it tracks many things regarding machine status.

One of the things I want to track is network configuration.

- list of network interfaces
- ipv4
- ipv6
- name

### Question

I have no problem to get list of the network devices ([SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1517090-scnetworkinterfacecopyall?language=objc)), or fetching its MAC address or BSD name.

I have problem fetching information about machine IP address for both protocols (IPv4 and IPv6).

I've tried use [SCNetworkInterfaceGetConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1516867-scnetworkinterfacegetconfigurati?language=occ) and [SCNetworkInterfaceGetExtendedConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1517315-scnetworkinterfacegetextendedcon?language=occ), but I've got only null values and [SCError](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1516922-scerror?language=occ) returns [kSCStatusInvalidArgument](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1518026-status_and_error_codes?language=objc).

In case of `SCNetworkInterfaceGetExtendedConfiguration` I used values: `kSCEntNetIPSec`, `kSCEntNetIPv4`, `kSCEntNetIPv6`.

Documentation is not precise and clear, so I've [found some project](https://github.com/aosm/configd/blob/master/SystemConfiguration.fproj/SCNetworkService.c) where this API is used, this give me some hints, but still doesn't help.

What I'm doing wrong?

Here some test code I'm using to explore API (it is C++ code since I'm porting application to Mac):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#include <SystemConfiguration/SCPreferences.h>
#include <SystemConfiguration/SCNetwork.h>
#include <SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkReachability.h>
#include <SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkConnection.h>
#include <SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkConfiguration.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

inline void myRelease(CFTypeRef p)
{
    if (p) CFRelease(p);
}

inline std::string toStd(CFStringRef s)
{
    if (!s) {
        return {};
    }
    if (auto fastCString = CFStringGetCStringPtr(s, kCFStringEncodingUTF8)) {
        return fastCString;
    }
    auto len = CFStringGetLength(s);
    auto size = CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding(CFStringGetLength(s), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) + 1;
    std::string result(size, '\0');

    CFStringGetBytes(s, { 0, len }, kCFStringEncodingUTF8, '?', 0,
                     reinterpret_cast<UInt8 *>(&result[0]), result.size(), &size);
    result.resize(size);

    return result;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, CFStringRef s) {
    return out << toStd(s);
}

struct DebugCf {
    DebugCf(CFTypeRef p) : mP(p) {}
    std::string toString() const {
        if (!mP) {
            return "<null>";
        }
        auto idOfType = CFGetTypeID(mP);
        if (CFStringGetTypeID() == idOfType) {
           return toStd((CFStringRef)mP);
        }
        auto s = CFCopyDescription(mP);
        auto result = toStd(s);
        CFRelease(s);

        return result;
    }

private:
    CFTypeRef mP;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const DebugCf d) {
    return out << d.toString();
}

#define LOGCF(x) " " #x "["<< DebugCf(x) << "], "

std::string SCErrorString()
{
    switch (SCError()) {
        case kSCStatusOK: return "OK";
        case kSCStatusFailed: return "Failed";
        case kSCStatusInvalidArgument: return "InvalidArgument";
        case kSCStatusAccessError: return "AccessError";
        case kSCStatusNoKey: return "NoKey";
        case kSCStatusKeyExists: return "KeyExists";
        case kSCStatusLocked: return "Locked";
        case kSCStatusNeedLock: return "NeedLock";
        case kSCStatusNoStoreSession: return "NoStoreSession";
        case kSCStatusNoStoreServer: return "NoStoreServer";
        case kSCStatusNotifierActive: return "NotifierActive";
        case kSCStatusNoPrefsSession: return "NoPrefsSession";
        case kSCStatusPrefsBusy: return "PrefsBusy";
        case kSCStatusNoConfigFile: return "NoConfigFile";
        case kSCStatusNoLink: return "NoLink";
        case kSCStatusStale: return "Stale";
        case kSCStatusMaxLink: return "MaxLink";
        case kSCStatusReachabilityUnknown: return "ReachabilityUnknown";

        default:
            return std::to_string(SCError());
    }
}

void exploreInterface(SCNetworkInterfaceRef netInterface) {
    auto macString = SCNetworkInterfaceGetHardwareAddressString(netInterface);
    auto bsdName = SCNetworkInterfaceGetBSDName(netInterface);

    std::cout << bsdName << ' ' << macString << '\n';

    CFDictionaryRef current = NULL;
    CFDictionaryRef active = NULL;
    CFArrayRef available = NULL;

    auto result = SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaOptions(netInterface,
                                                     &current,
                                                     &active,
                                                     &available,
                                                     1);

    std::cout << "SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaOptions: "
        << (bool)result << " e=" << SCErrorString()
        // << LOGCF(current) << LOGCF(active) << LOGCF(available)
        << '\n';

    auto interfaceConfig = SCNetworkInterfaceGetConfiguration(netInterface);
    std::cout << "SCNetworkInterfaceGetConfiguration: " << LOGCF(interfaceConfig)
            << "e = " << SCErrorString() << '\n';


    auto interfaceExtConfig = SCNetworkInterfaceGetExtendedConfiguration(netInterface, kSCEntNetIPSec);
    std::cout << "SCNetworkInterfaceGetExtendedConfiguration: " << LOGCF(interfaceExtConfig)
        << "e = " << SCErrorString() << '\n';

    std::cout << "SCNetworkInterfaceGetInterfaceType: "
        << SCNetworkInterfaceGetInterfaceType(netInterface)
        << "  SCNetworkInterfaceGetLocalizedDisplayName: "
        << SCNetworkInterfaceGetLocalizedDisplayName(netInterface) << '\n';

    auto supportedProtocols = SCNetworkInterfaceGetSupportedProtocolTypes(netInterface);
    std::cout << "SCNetworkInterfaceGetSupportedProtocolTypes: "
    << LOGCF(supportedProtocols) << '\n';

    myRelease(current);
    myRelease(active);
    myRelease(available);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    auto allNetwork = SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll();

    auto count = CFArrayGetCount(allNetwork);
    for (CFIndex i=0; i<count; ++i) {
        auto netInterface = (SCNetworkInterfaceRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allNetwork, i);
        exploreInterface(netInterface);
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }
    CFRelease(allNetwork);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fwiw; i wrote this up in swift and it also returns nil for SCNetworkInterfaceGetConfiguration and the extended call. Might this approach work;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795798/how-to-determine-netmask-of-active-interface-in-objective-c-on-a-mac

Comment: have you checked source of MenuMeter?  https://github.com/yujitach/MenuMeters

Comment: @Hofi thanks this was very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Hofi and @johnelemans for help. This hints was enough to find answer.
For others which could have similar problem:

To fetch Mac address [SCDynamicStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scdynamicstore?language=objc) must be used. From that I can [fetch BSD name](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1516854-scnetworkinterfacegetbsdname?language=objc) which is needed later to fetch connection details.

Now use of [SCDynamicStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scdynamicstore?language=objc) API is a bit strange.
To explore what can be done there is command line tool: [`scutil`](https://ss64.com/osx/scutil.html).
It is best to run it without parameters and type this commands:

```
list
list State:/Network/Interfaces/.*
get State:/Network/Interface/en0/IPv6
d.show
```

I've found [examples here](https://00f.net/2011/08/14/programmatically-changing-network-configuration-on-osx/).

Based on information gained from this tool I've come up how to fetch needed data.
Test code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

inline void myRelease(CFTypeRef p)
{
    if (p) CFRelease(p);
}

inline std::string toStd(CFStringRef s)
{
    if (!s) {
        return {};
    }
    if (auto fastCString = CFStringGetCStringPtr(s, kCFStringEncodingUTF8)) {
        return fastCString;
    }
    auto len = CFStringGetLength(s);
    auto size = CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding(CFStringGetLength(s), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) + 1;
    std::string result(size, '\0');

    CFStringGetBytes(s, { 0, len }, kCFStringEncodingUTF8, '?', 0,
                     reinterpret_cast<UInt8 *>(&result[0]), result.size(), &size);
    result.resize(size);

    return result;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, CFStringRef s) {
    return out << toStd(s);
}

struct DebugCf {
    DebugCf(CFTypeRef p) : mP(p) {}
    std::string toString() const {
        if (!mP) {
            return "<null>";
        }
        auto idOfType = CFGetTypeID(mP);
        if (CFStringGetTypeID() == idOfType) {
           return toStd((CFStringRef)mP);
        }
        auto s = CFCopyDescription(mP);
        auto result = toStd(s);
        CFRelease(s);

        return result;
    }

private:
    CFTypeRef mP;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const DebugCf d) {
    return out << d.toString();
}

#define LOGCF(x) " " #x "["<< DebugCf(x) << "], "

std::string SCErrorString()
{
    switch (SCError()) {
        case kSCStatusOK: return "OK";
        case kSCStatusFailed: return "Failed";
        case kSCStatusInvalidArgument: return "InvalidArgument";
        case kSCStatusAccessError: return "AccessError";
        case kSCStatusNoKey: return "NoKey";
        case kSCStatusKeyExists: return "KeyExists";
        case kSCStatusLocked: return "Locked";
        case kSCStatusNeedLock: return "NeedLock";
        case kSCStatusNoStoreSession: return "NoStoreSession";
        case kSCStatusNoStoreServer: return "NoStoreServer";
        case kSCStatusNotifierActive: return "NotifierActive";
        case kSCStatusNoPrefsSession: return "NoPrefsSession";
        case kSCStatusPrefsBusy: return "PrefsBusy";
        case kSCStatusNoConfigFile: return "NoConfigFile";
        case kSCStatusNoLink: return "NoLink";
        case kSCStatusStale: return "Stale";
        case kSCStatusMaxLink: return "MaxLink";
        case kSCStatusReachabilityUnknown: return "ReachabilityUnknown";

        default:
            return std::to_string(SCError());
    }
}

void exploreServiceQuery(CFStringRef query, CFStringRef serviceId, SCDynamicStoreRef scSession) {
    auto resolvedQuery =
    CFStringCreateWithFormat(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                             NULL,
                             query, serviceId);

    auto dic = (CFDictionaryRef)SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(scSession,
                                                        resolvedQuery);

    std::cout << resolvedQuery << " - " << LOGCF(dic) << '\n';

    myRelease(dic);
    CFRelease(resolvedQuery);
}

void printIpv4Data(SCDynamicStoreRef scSession,
                   CFStringRef bsdName) {
    exploreServiceQuery(CFSTR("State:/Network/Interface/%@/IPv4"),
                        bsdName,
                        scSession);
}

void printIpv6Data(SCDynamicStoreRef scSession,
                   CFStringRef bsdName) {
    exploreServiceQuery(CFSTR("State:/Network/Interface/%@/IPv6"),
                        bsdName,
                        scSession);
}

void desiriedData() {
    auto allInterfaces = SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll();

    auto scSession = SCDynamicStoreCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          CFSTR("Custom"),
                                          NULL,
                                          NULL);

    auto count = CFArrayGetCount(allInterfaces);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        auto netInterface = (SCNetworkInterfaceRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allInterfaces, i);

        auto macString = SCNetworkInterfaceGetHardwareAddressString(netInterface);
        auto bsdName = SCNetworkInterfaceGetBSDName(netInterface);

        std::cout << bsdName << " " << macString << '\n';
        printIpv4Data(scSession, bsdName);
        printIpv6Data(scSession, bsdName);
    }

    CFRelease(scSession);
    CFRelease(allInterfaces);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    desiriedData();

    return 0;
}
```